# Diff. b/w performance results shown with Jmeter and Firebug-Net Panel

Tags: java, performance, firebug, jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to test the performance of an application through JMeter , I found the result using aggregate report but the reports were showing low performance in comparison to what I found using Firebug-Net Panel. So what exactly is the difference b/w the timings shown in Firebug-Net Panel and Jmeter. Also I have enabled caching in Jmeter so that a real scenario is implemented. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to fire your test from command line instead of GUI?

Comment: Not tried that option, but even if I try will that make any difference. One more point the performance shows significant improvement(similar to Firebug-Net Panel) if I uncheck "Embedded Resources" option(css,images and js).

Comment: Net panel uses cache immediately and jMeter's first request is without cache. Try deleting the cache (Ctrl+Shift+Delete) and then try loading the page with Net panel. And yes, you should try without GUI.

Comment: Yes!! I understand ur point to delete cache and then try loading, but in order to create a real user scenario I want to enable cache.In order to emulate this behaviour with Jmeter I tried two options (i) Disable embedded requests (ii)Http Cache Manager .But  I'm still confused about the right approach.

Comment: I'm not talking about user scenarios, I'm just trying to help you find the answer to your question (discrepancy between jMeter & Firebug). Have you tried my suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Different tools perform different kinds of bytecode sampling and instrumentation. You will always find discrepancy between tools measuring performance. This is why you should be looking at this numbers magnitude wise and not their literal value. Just pay attention to magnitudes and not scalar values.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the firebug during the load and got different measurements? Although the two tools  work differently, they should both show the same **change** in performance. I mean that if for example at some point (e.g. 50 concurrent users load), the response time doubles, this should reflect the same in firebug as well as in JMeter.